# Is it possible to keep an AJAX request active after user navigates to another page of the website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, scope

I am having a website where a user submits a form using ajax. The response is shown in alert whether the form was successfully submitted or the details of the problem. Now since this process is asynchronous, if the user navigates to another page before the response is received, the `XMLHttpRequest` object that was used for submitting the form is deleted and the user does not get feedback about the status of the submitted form.

So, is it possible to have the `XMLHttpRequest` object remain active even if the user navigates to another page?

Comment: Why don't you utilize cookies? That's a better solution.

Comment: Or local/session storage.

Comment: Or opaque the page until a response is received.

Comment: I don't see how either cookies or local storage would help at all here.

Comment: neither of the first two suggestions would make a difference if the user navigates away from the page before there's a response from the server

Comment: Yeah, cookies and local storage won't fix anything - the HTTP request will abort as soon as the page unloads. You'd have to implement something like PJAX so page navigation is loaded via AJAX instead of individual pageviews.

Comment: That duplicate post does not solve the problem and is merely minor related to it.

Comment: @ceejayoz, doesn't it actually go the other way around? I mean, the page will wait for XHR to finish before it unloads. I'm not sure but that's what I always thought.

Comment: Usually you get a status 0 response when the XHR gets cancelled in between. Not sure if that is supposed to be but it is my experience.

Comment: @matewka If the user clicks a link or closes the page, the XHR will not finish. Sites like Facebook/Twitter load all in-site navigation via AJAX for this reason.

Comment: @Cerbrus I did not find my solution in the post you marked duplicate. Could you also tell me how I can use local/session storage in my case?

Comment: Oh, apparently the title of the OP doesn't describe the problem of the OP. If someone has a better dupe, feel free to change it.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have corrected the title to reflect my problem. Could you elaborate about your suggestion on local/session storage?

Comment: Local / session storage won't help if you navigate away from the page before the request finished loading.

Comment: @Dean.DePue I have gone with your suggestion of **Opeque the page** and showed a simple animation till the response is received.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is it possible to have the XMLHttpRequest object remain active even if the user navigates to another page?

No, it's not. The XMLHttpRequest is part of the previous page's context, and disappears along with it.

The best solution is to somehow prevent the user from navigating away from the page until the request is finished. The [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) event might come in handy here.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` would probably be a better choice - the user might have legitimate reasons for closing the window or navigating away.